# Read multiple files, search for string and store in a list

Tags: python, regex, list, file-read

I am trying to search through a list of files, look for the words 'type' and the following word. then put them into a list with the file name.  So for example this is what I am looking for.

```
File Name, Type

[1.txt, [a, b, c]]
[2.txt, [a,b]]
```

My current code  returns a list for every type.

```
[1.txt, [a]]
[1.txt, [b]]
[1.txt, [c]]
[2.txt, [a]]
[2.txt, [b]]
```

Here is my code, i know my logic will return a single value into the list but I'm not sure how to edit it to it will just be the file name with a list of types.

```
output = []
for file_name in find_files(d):
    with open(file_name, 'r') as f:
        for line in f:
            line = line.lower().strip()
            match = re.findall('type ([a-z]+)', line)
            if match:
                output.append([file_name, match])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Learn to categorize your actions at the proper loop level.
In this case, you say that you want to accumulate all of the references into a single list, but then your code creates one output line per reference, rather than one per file.  Change that focus:

```
with open(file_name, 'r') as f:
    ref_list = []
    for line in f:
        line = line.lower().strip()
        match = re.findall('type ([a-z]+)', line)
        if match:
            ref_list.append(match)

    # Once you've been through the entire file,
    #   THEN you add a line for that file,
    #    with the entire reference list
    output.append([file_name, ref_list])
```

Comment: thank you that was helpful, still learning! think there is a slight typo with the last statement, match should be ref_list.

Comment: Good catch; thanks!  I fixed it.
You realize, of course, that you're in significant danger of knowing what you're doing ... :-)

Answer (score 1):

You might find it useful to use a [`dict`](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries) here instead

```py
output = {}
for file_name in find_files(d):
    with open(file_name, 'r') as f:
        output[file_name] = []
        for line in f:
            line = line.lower().strip()
            match = re.findall('type ([a-z]+)', line)
            if match:
                output[file_name].append(*match)
```